# Symmetric Matrix Question

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm given that A is a symmetric n x n matrix.  Is this also symmetric:

$$2I_n + 3A - 4A^2 ?$$

I know that a symmetric matrix satisfies $A = A^T$ but not really sure how to use that in this case.

Is there a property of symmetric matrices that would make this easy to figure out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

$$B:=-4A^2+3A+2I\implies B^t=\left(-4A^2+3A+2I\right)^t=-4(A^2)^t+3A^t+2I=\ldots$$

Use  $\;(A^2)^t=(A^t)^2\;$ ...

Comment: Continuing above: = $-4(A^t)^2 + 3A + 2I$ = $-4A^2 + 3A + 2I$

Comment: Indeed so, @Mariogs ...:) +1

Answer (score 1):

Take the transpose of that matrix and check whether it equals itself.  You'll need to use some properties of the transpose such as

- $(A + B)^t = A^t + B^t$ when $A, B$ are matrices,
- $(AB)^t = B^tA^t$ when $A, B$ are matrices,
- $(kA)^t = kA^t$ when $A$ is a matrix and $k$ is a scalar.